# Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, html

I'm working with a pagination and I get this error is the first time I work with this, I a appreciate the help thank you!

```
try {

    // Find out how many items are in the table
    $total = $con -> query('SELECT company_name, email, tel, website 
             FROM company') -> fetch_assoc();

    // How many items to list per page
        $limit = 10;
    // How many pages will there be
         $pages = mysqli_fetch_array($total, $limit);
    // What page are we currently on?
         $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array (
             'option' => array(
                 'default' => 1,
                 'min_range' => 1,
             ),
         )));
    // Calculate the offset for the query
         $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    // Some information to display to the user
         $start = $offset + 1;
         $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);
    // The "back" link
         $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a herf="?page=1" title = "First page"> &laquo;</a>
       <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span 
   class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';
    // The "forward" link
  $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next
   page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : 
   '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';  



  }

catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
}
```

This is the line I getting the error.

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\pritcluster\register_companies.php on line 212

```
       // Display the paging information
  echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ',
      $pages, ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total,
      'results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';
```

Comment: `$pages` is an array. You can't use it like a string.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because `$pages` is an array. It looks like you want to spit out the number of items in that array, in which case you should replace `$pages` with `count($pages)`.

```
echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ',
      count($pages), ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', count($total),
      'results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';
```

The same also applies to  `$total`.

Comment: Try putting a `count()` around `$total` as well, for the same reason.

Comment: I fix it! in the variable $total need to put the same thing count($total) Thank you!!!

Comment: Yeah I put it in that variable.

Comment: Sidenote: This `<a herf="?page=1"` should be `<a href="?page=1"` @user3014210 - Typo.